# How do I convert the query results to variable in dart

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart

I have stored the value of column id from the SQL table in a variable and it is stored in this format `(Fields: {id: 15})`. I want to extract the id from this set and assign it to an integer.

MY Query:

```
var res =await connmysql.query("SELECT id FROM yourname Where name = '$name'");
```

when I am printing res it is printing like `(Fields: {id: 15})` but I want the id to store it in an integer variable.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Please read a tutorial on mysql, the proper way to do this is right on the front page on how to use the package.

Answer (score 0):

you can extract id and store into variable like this:

```
var id = Fields['id'];
```